# Getting a SessionFactory in Spring Boot 2.0 / Hibernate 5

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I was using `HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean` in Spring Boot 1.5.x to get a session factory bean for my sessions. Since that's deprecated now, I'm trying to use the session factory by unwrapping in an EntityManagerFactory. But, I can't get EntityManagerFactory to be autowired. There's no bean defining it.

What do I need to do to wire in an EntityManagerFactory? entityManagerFactory remains null.

```
/**
 * A class to hold necessary data access beans.
 */
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DataBeans {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    /**
     * This bean needs to be wired in so that a SessionFactory can be wired in to other data access beans.
     *
     * @return a session factory bean
     */
    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactoryProvider() {
        return entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
    }
}



@SpringBootApplication
public class AppBootMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AppBootMain.class, args);
    }
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:student_db
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop

# this ensures that a session factory bean is available
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
```

Note: i tried changing the `current_session_context_class` to specify hibernate5 in the package, but no success.

error running bootRun:
```

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataBeans': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'entityManagerFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactoryProvider' defined in class path resource [org/webapp/example/school/data/repository/DataBeans.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'dataBeans' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'sessionFactoryProvider' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:587)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1348)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$94/681094281.getObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243)
    at org.webapp.example.school.AppBootMain.main(AppBootMain.java:27)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactoryProvider' defined in class path resource [org/webapp/example/school/data/repository/DataBeans.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'dataBeans' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'sessionFactoryProvider' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:587)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$94/681094281.getObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'dataBeans' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'sessionFactoryProvider' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:579)
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.webapp.example.school.data.repository.DataBeans.sessionFactoryProvider(DataBeans.java:30)
    at org.webapp.example.school.data.repository.DataBeans$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ebde0844.CGLIB$sessionFactoryProvider$0(<generated>)
    at org.webapp.example.school.data.repository.DataBeans$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ebde0844$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f2417c25.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361)
    at org.webapp.example.school.data.repository.DataBeans$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ebde0844.sessionFactoryProvider(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 34 common frames omitted

> Task :bootRun FAILED
```

I tried putting EntityManagerFactory as a paraemter to the bean method that creatrs teh session factory, but it failed due to circular dependency.

```
    @Bean
public SessionFactory sessionFactoryProvider(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    return entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
}
```

Comment: show the DAO class

Comment: Did you resolve the issue ? Even I am facing circular dependency issue.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered the same problem when upgrade from 1.5 to 2.1.3 and resolved by getting the Session / SessionFactory in the Dao class instead of autowire when spring init.

Following is an example:

1. Remove the DataBeans in you example
2. In the Dao classes use following to get the Session:

```java
@Repository
@Transactional
public class XXXDao {
    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    private Session getSession() {
        return entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    }
...
}
```

If you really need the SessionFactory, use following coding and beware that the you might need to handle the transaction manually.

```java
@Repository
public class XXXDao {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    private SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
    }
...
}
```

I would suggest you check also the
[Spring boot hibernate no transaction is in progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50650041/spring-boot-hibernate-no-transaction-is-in-progress) for the transaction issue

Answer (score 0):

I did the same as you but without @EnableTransactionManagement.

Here my class and properties.

```
@Configuration
public class SessionFactoryConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
         return entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
    }
}
```

> spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
>   spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
>   spring.datasource.username=postgres
>   spring.datasource.password=postgres
>
> spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
>   spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=false
>   spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=10
>   spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=true
>   spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
>        spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext

Adding @EnableTransactionManagement means Transaction will be enabled but you have to configure it via PlatformTransactionManager. Spring autoconfiguration will do it so you don't have to declare it.

Comment: So what you have is the same as I have, except for @EnableTransactionManagement. I removed that, but entityManagerFactory is still null.