# Spring boot hibernate no transaction is in progress

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I'm using spring boot and it perfectly makes me entity manager. And I decided to test getting session factory from the entity manager and to use it for an example. But I get the next problem:`javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress`

properties

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ring
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=root

spring.jpa.show-sql = false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=false

#Note: The last two properties on the code snippet above were added to suppress an annoying exception
# that occurs when JPA (Hibernate) tries to verify PostgreSQL CLOB feature.
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults = false

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class = org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
```

service class

```
package kz.training.springrest.service;

import kz.training.springrest.entity.User;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit;

@Service
public class UserService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional
    public void insertUser(User user) {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class).getSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.save(user);
    }

}
```

runner

```
package kz.training.springrest.run;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaAuditing;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan("kz.training.springrest.entity")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages="kz.training.springrest")
public class SpringrestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringrestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Do you have any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: You should not write dao code  in service class. You should create a @Repository interface or class and perform dao operations there.

Comment: Should @EnableTransactionManagement be on a class also annotated with @Configuration?

Comment: I know that this code must be in @repository, but it doesn't solve my problem

Comment: @EnableTransactionManagement can also be on spring boot runner

Comment: @ShubhamKadlag That's honestly highly subjective statement.  A lot of people view the JPA abstraction as _the DAO_ and simply use it inside their services, particularly if the application never intends to work with anything but JPA.  To me adding a `@Repository` here is just another layer of abstraction atop of an existing abstraction which effectively just adds extra function calls to the stack with little to no meaning or reward.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't quite understand why you're making your service method so unnecessarily complex.  You should simply be able to do it this way

```
@Transactional
public void insertUser(User user) {
  entityManager.persist( user );
}
```

If there are points where you need access to the native Hibernate `Session` you can simply unwrap and use the `Session` directly like this:

```
@Transactional
public void doSomethingFancyWithASession() {
  Session session = entityManager.unwrap( Session.class );
  // use session as needed
}
```

The notion here is that Spring provides you an already functional `EntityManager` instance by you using the `@PersistenceContext` annotation.  That instance will safely be usable by the current thread your spring bean is being executed within.

Secondly, by using `@Transactional`, this causes Spring's transaction management to automatically make sure that the `EntityManager` is bound to a transaction, whether that is a `RESOURCE_LOCAL` or `JTA` transaction is based on your environment configuration.

You're running into your problem because of the call to `#getCurrentSession()`.

What is happening is Spring creates the `EntityManager`, then inside your method when you make the call to `#getCurrentSession()`, you're asking Hibernate to create a second session that is not bound to the transaction started by your `@Transactional` annotation.  In short its  essentially akin to the following:

```
EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
Session aNewSession = entityManager.unwrap( Session.class )
  .getFactory()
  .getCurrentSession();
// at this point entityManager is scoped to a transaction
// aNewSession is not scoped to any transaction
// this also likely uses 2 connections to the database which is a waste
```

So follow the paradigm I mention above and you should no longer run into the problem.  You should never need to call `#getCurrentSession()` or `#openSession()` in a Spring environment if you're properly allowing Spring to inject your `EntityManager` instance for you.

Comment: Thank you a lot) It's the perfect explanation)

Answer (score 0):

I have same your error, when I deploy my spring boot app to WebLogic Server.
(Even It works fine if I run it directly via Eclipse (Or deploy to Tomcat) ).

I solved the problem by adding @EnableTransactionManagement to UserService.

Answer (score 0):

salved my problem using in hibernate conf  **"hibernate.allow_update_outside_transaction","true"**