# getSession comes as null in Spring Boot 2.5 / Hibernate 5

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I am working on spring boot 2.5 and Hibernate 5 but my getSession always comes as null. Below is the code I have. I have googled but the answers are for spring boot up to version 2.

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
```

and

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Repository
@Transactional
public class ABC{
    
     @Autowired
        private EntityManager entityManager;

        private Session getSession() {
            //below line always return null/null pointer for me
            return entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);         
        }
    
    public String gettingSession() {        
        getSession();
        //I am trying to run queries like below after i get the session.
    //  List<EMP> employee=(List<EMP>) getSession().createQuery("from EMP").list();
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

I tried below links and getting same null/null pointer:

- [Spring Boot - Handle to Hibernate SessionFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25063995/spring-boot-handle-to-hibernate-sessionfactory)
- [Getting a SessionFactory in Spring Boot 2.0 / Hibernate 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50317045/getting-a-sessionfactory-in-spring-boot-2-0-hibernate-5)

Comment: (1) You need to show where you're calling these methods from. (2) You should use `@PersistenceContext` for an `EntityManager`, not `@Autowired`. (3) Use the JPA interfaces rather than the legacy Hibernate interfaces. (4) Just use Spring Data; this entire class can be replaced with an empty interface declaration.

Comment: If changing the annotation as chrylis suggested doesn't work, then we have to question if you're creating the object using `new ABC()` or injecting it via spring-boot. If it's the first way, then of course the entityManager is null, because you're not invoking the mechanisms that fill it. Secondly you really shouldn't be using the `Session` interface. Use `EntityManager` as it is more reliable for future compatibility.

Comment: As chrylis suggested by using @PersistenceContext issue got resolved. Thanks.