# Spring 3 to Spring 5 Migration - Build Error

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have upgraded an old Project from Spring 3 to Spring 5. The Application works as expected when I deploy it directly from my Eclipse IDE to Tomcat 9. However, when I build a war file using `mvn clean install` and deploy it on Tomcat 9 server, I get the following error -

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.abc.model.dao.impl.ApiFormDaoImpl]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/HibernateDaoSupport.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:189)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:320)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:237)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:280)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:96)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:707)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:533)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4716)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5177)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:706)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:946)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1792)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:757)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:426)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1520)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:843)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
```

**ApiFormDaoImpl**

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly=true)
@Component
@Repository("apiFormDao")
public class ApiFormDaoImpl extends GenericEntityDaoImpl  implements ApiFormDao {
    @Autowired
    GenericEntityDao genericEntityDao;

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    ...
}
```

I am not sure where to begin looking for the problem. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: I suggest you for not taking a so long version jump. Convert first to latest version 3, first version 4, latest version 4, first version 5 and latest version 5. And in each check for errors.  Also it seams you are trying to use Hibernate 3, but in Spring 5, hibernate version is 5.

Comment: @pringi Thanks for the response. I actually have done the same. I upgraded the application from 3 to 4 and then to 5. I weeded out all the issues and got it running on Tomcat 9 with Spring 5. Also, I am using Hibernate 5. There is no mention of Hibernate 3 in the project as of now. This is why I am stumped as to why I am getting this error after deploying the war file.

Comment: I think your problem is with the SessionFactory. Can you see if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50317045/getting-a-sessionfactory-in-spring-boot-2-0-hibernate-5